# android sqlite - instantiate-create-insert-search for elements

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android. I would like to create a database that will contain a name and phone number. I need to add in this database or to modify the phone number element. 
Can someone please help me with creating a table with this two elements in database and check if a specific name exists. If no I want to create add add it in the table. If the name exists I want to be able to modify the phoe number. I want to create the table just once. I think I also need to check if the table is created or no.

Can someone give me a full android example with instantiate, create, insert, delete or modify or search elements in a database? Please?

Appreciate,. Thank you

Based on the example with the student database (`http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/introduction-to-android-sqlite-database`)

I have:

```
if (cursor != null) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                if (cursor.getString(1).equals("me")) value=i;
                Log.i("Student", "Student Name: " + cursor.getString(1)
                        + " Grade " + cursor.getString(2));

                i=i+1;
            }
        }

        Cursor cursor1 = dbUtil1.fetchStudent(value);
        if (cursor1 != null) {
            //while (cursor1.moveToNext())
            {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Student "+ "Student Name: " + cursor1.getString(1)
                        + " Grade " + cursor1.getString(2),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //i=i+1;
            }
        }
```

but is not working properly. where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very good introduction to Android SQLite database via a sample application : http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/introduction-to-android-sqlite-database/

Comment: thank yoou very much for your post. Based on the example you sent I would like to ask how to call the method fetchStudent(long id)? How to retrive the id of a specific student (based on the Student Name). Can you please help me?

Comment: There is sample code shown in the example towards the end of the article. The sample are shown for 2 of the methods i.e. `createStudent` and `fetchAllStudents`. You can call the `fetchStudent` in a similar manner. Just pass in the unique id of the record.

Comment: but how to find the unique id?. Can you please post an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db